# Xamarin form MessagingCenter Unsubscribe is not working as expected

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Functionality written inside the MessagingCenter.Subscribe() is called multiple times when i navigate to and fro multiple times in the application. But each time before subscribing, i do unsubscribe to the same in constructor as follows, still it didn't worked.

```
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<SubmitPage>(this,"Save");
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SubmitPage>(this, "Save", (sender) =>
{
   DisplayToastOnSuccessfulSubmission();
});
```

In my application i have 6 pages([git](https://github.com/suchithm/MessageCenterSampleApp)) and i save the data in 6th page with MessagingCenter.Send and same will be subscribed in 2nd page and saved message will be displayed in 2nd page(after navigating to that page).

Now i navigate like 2->1->2->3->4->5->6 in this particular case DisplayToastOnSuccessfulSubmission() would be called two times(because Page2 constructor is called twice).

I even tried placing the same code in OnAppearing.
I can't unsubscribe in OnDisappear as I need the event wiring up to when I reach Page6 for save.

Reproduced the same behaviour in sample project and added here https://github.com/suchithm/MessageCenterSampleApp 
 [Drop box link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/72joc4ttb7yr2ge/MsgCenterSample.zip?dl=0)

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I don't have a solution right now, but I think I see the problem. You're calling the constructor, so it's a new instance. `this` is not the same instance anymore. This means that the event is never actually unsubscribed on your first instance.

Comment: Ya if it is the completely new instance then how it get calls one more time for each navigation

Comment: My guess is that the first instance is not disposed

Comment: [Try this below code to use single instance messaging centre to avoid multiple subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340275/xamarin-forms-messagingcenter-subscribe-called-two-times/72633153#72633153)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But each time before subscribing, I do unsubscribe to the same in constructor as follows, still it didn't worked.

`MessagingCenter.Subscribe()` is called multiple times, because **there are two instances of Page2** in your code, both of them use `MessagingCenter.Subscribe()` method, that's why the `Unsubscribe` didn't work.

You can modify `page2()` to a **singleton** to make sure there is only one instance of `Page2` in your project, after that when you send a message, 
  the `MessagingCenter.Subscribe()` is called only once.

Page2.cs:

```
public static Page2 instance = new Page2();

public static Page2 GetPage2Instance()
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        return new Page2();
    }
    return instance;
}

private Page2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Page2>(this, "SaveToastPage2");
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page2>(this, "SaveToastPage2", (sender) =>
    {
       DisplayToastOnSuccessfulSubmission();
    }
 }
```

When you send a message :

```
MessagingCenter.Send(Page2.GetPage2Instance(), "SaveToastPage2");
```

**EDIT** :

Remember that declaring  constructors of `Page2` class to be private to make sure there is only one instance of `Page2` in your project sure.

```
private Page2()
{
   ...
}
```

Modify your `Page1.cs` code :

```
async void Handle_Next(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    await App.NavigationRef.PushAsync(Page2.GetPage2Instance(), true);
}
```

Comment: I have added the singleton class as mentioned, but still it calls multiple times.

Comment: Please update your code in github, I will try to find a solution.

Comment: This is the good catch!. It is working now as expected, kudos :)

Comment: I have tried singleton method. However the problem is when the app is restored from sleep. It becomes a blank page...

Comment: I was creating an instance of my mediator page every time a user would log in, Singleton fixed it for me :)

Comment: Modifying page/view model to singleton has side effects. When navigating back to this same page again in the app it displays previous content before InitializeAsync of the view-model is called and new model could be loaded and front end updated. It looks a bit off on the screen when it happens. Any advice on this ? Regards Mariusz

Comment: Actually I just found out that when a view model is a singleton its constructor is called only once. This is why it doesn't subscribe multiple times to this same message in my case.

Answer (score 4):

I faced same issue. I solved issue by passing the same parameters inn subscribe and unsubscribing as well.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page1, T>(this, "Listen", async (Page1 arg1, T 
listenedString) =>
{

});
```

Unsubscribe like below

```
 MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Page1, T>(this, "Listen");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this temporary solution.
I declared a static dictionary to storage my object (to this example I used an object type).

```
private static Dictionary<string, object> subscribedReferencePages = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

And I always storage the last subscribed page reference.
Then I compare the page reference before triggering the message method to fire only the last one.

```
    subscribedReferencePages[pageName] = this;
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ViewModelBase>(this, pageName, async (sender) =>
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(sender, this))
        {
            return;
        }

        this.OnInitialized();
    });
```

To call the message method I need to pass the dictionary as parameter (instead of the "this" reference).

```
 MessagingCenter.Send(subscribedPages[pageName], keyPageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unsubscribing when you navigate TO a page,
unsubscribe when you navigate AWAY from the page.  At that point your instance of 'this' is still the same 'this' you think it is.